# Trying to launch a url using asynctask - android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to launch a url in android using asynctask, the code shows no error but when I launch the application instead of the url displaying, it displays "hello world" to the screen. Below is my attempt:

```
//Starting the task. Pass an url as the parameter.
        new PostTask().execute("http://www.google.com");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    // The definition of our task class
    private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       String url=params[0];
       for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5) {
         try {
           Thread.sleep(50);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
          publishProgress(i);
       }
       return "All Done!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
    }
```

EDITTED:
This is my activity_main.xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.project.unityapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my application is not opening the url on launch. Kindly assist.

Comment: add your activity_main.xml code, I think you didn't add a webview to your layout

Comment: It seems you are not doing anything with the url passed into your task

Comment: I have added my activity_main.xml code

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?you are not doing anything with the url passed in doInBackground method.If you want to load the webpage on that particular url use webview.

Comment: okay. is not possible to load a webpage using asyntack except with webview. I am new to asynctask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the webpage of that url use webview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.project.unityapp.MainActivity" >


<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

Comment: this is not using asynctask

Comment: If you want to display the page this much required. Can you please specify what is actually your goal

Comment: My goal is stated in my problem statement, using asynctask to render a web page

Comment: Why you need asynctask, without that its possible.

Comment: I have read that asynctask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread

Comment: Ya thats right. But in the case of HTTP connection and network actions like API calls, server authentication etc. In the case of webview we can manage without asynctask.
If you use any API calls you need to use asynctask, then the result of that API call you will get on 'onPostExecute' method

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what do you want to do by passing the url.
Asynctask is use to get data or something you want to do in background from url which you pass.
In this scenario you are not using the url which you pass in doInBackground method.